# python unittest: TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm working with `unittest.Testcase()`. I'm inheriting several times so I've children children tests. How ever, when I start some of my children, the python3 interpreter comes which such a stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/248/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1483, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/248/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/snap/pycharm-community/248/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py", line 35, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 100, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 147, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py", line 159, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 220, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 193, in loadTestsFromName
    return self.loadTestsFromTestCase(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py", line 93, in loadTestsFromTestCase
    loaded_suite = self.suiteClass(map(testCaseClass, testCaseNames))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/suite.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.addTests(tests)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/unittest/suite.py", line 57, in addTests
    for test in tests:
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why, but in Unit test, you do not overwrite the `__init__()`-method.

What I wanted, was to overwrite `setUpClass()` and call `super()`.

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    super().setUpClass()
```

What I've done was that I used python default overwriting `__init__()`.

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
```

Fancy that, you'll receive this hilarious error message. Hope this could be some help to someone.